# strange "using where" in simple query

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have a table with this structure:

```
mysql> describe user_groups;

+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11) unsigned     | NO   | MUL | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id  | int(11) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| group_id | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

primary key of this table is : PRIMARY(user_id, group_id)
I have simple query:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT `UserGroup`.`user_id` , `UserGroup`.`group_id` FROM `user_groups` AS `UserGroup` WHERE `UserGroup`.`user_id` IN ( 1, 2 );
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | UserGroup | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    4 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

it has `using where;` , according it has additional disk seek,I know `using where;` concept, and Also I know it is not terrible , but conceptually I want to know why this query has `using where;`, although the condition is on primary key directly and it doesn't have order or anything that causes `using where;`.
How can I fix this `using where;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information).

> Using index
>
> The column information is retrieved from the table using only
>   information in the index tree without having to do an additional seek
>   to read the actual row. This strategy can be used when the query uses
>   only columns that are part of a single index.
>
> **If the Extra column also says Using where, it means the index is being
>   used to perform lookups of key values.** Without Using where, the
>   optimizer may be reading the index to avoid reading data rows but not
>   using it for lookups. For example, if the index is a covering index
>   for the query, the optimizer may scan it without using it for lookups.

In short, your query is working as intended and is not performing an additional disk seek.